# "like" vs. "as" Confusion in a sentence

Tags: meaning, differences, comparisons, as-like

Which is the correct sentence between the following:

1) He deserves the same fate as you

2) He deserves the same fate like you.

From my knowledge and understanding, the second sentence is correct because "as" must be used before  a clause (basically a verb) and "like" must be used before a noun. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Both are acceptable. They do not mean the same thing. "... the same fate as you" compares *fate;* "the same fate like you" compares the way it befell.

Comment: Kris,Can you please elaborate the difference you just pointed out?

Comment: Ask what fate --> "... the same fate as you." On the other hand, ask how --> "... the same fate like you." HTH.

Comment: Although grammatically it may not necessarily be so, pragmatics (common usage) can change the meaning.

Comment: Still confused...Can you share any link elucidating the same?

Comment: A more elaborate answer may be appropriate on [ell.se] -- let's see if the Q can be migrated there.

Comment: See if these may help you: http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g54.html http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-as http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Like_vs_As.htm http://www.beatthegmat.com/sc-like-versus-as-in-comparisons-t281227.html (I've not checked them yet.)

Answer (score 2):

You make a couple of false assumptions. Firstly, it is not true that "*as* must be used whenever you have a clause". *Like* can also be used to introduce a clause: *Nobody knows her like I do.*

There are numerous similar examples in *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage*. The MWDEU continues:

> These examples should suffice to show that conjunctive *like* is
>   widely used in standard English prose.

Secondly, it is not true that "*like* must be used whenever there is a noun following the word *like*". In informal English *as* can also be followed by a noun phrase: *She can't speak English as well as her brother*.

As to the two sentences, the standard construction is *the same .... as*, not *the same ... like*. So, *He deserves the same fate as you* is the standard choice here. It means *his fate should be the same fate as your fate*.

But as Kris points out, *He deserves the same fate like you* could possibly be interpreted somewhat differently.  For example, another interpretation is: *What he deserves is what you deserve*, where the comparison is on the *deserving* and not on the *fate*. So, he deserves person C's fate, in the same way that you deserve person C's fate.

Comment: However, "the same fate like you" is most likely to be intepreted as a mis-rendering of "the same fate as you", rather than any of the tortured interpretations suggested.

Comment: @Brian, I absolutely agree, hence my "_could *possibly* be interpreted somewhat differently_". This question, as very many on this site, asks about decontextualised sentences. In real life, it is very unlikely that the sentences would be open to alternative interpretations, such as I suggest here.

Comment: @Shoe: I liked your explanation but i beg to differ on some of the issues you pointed out:

1)Nobody knows her like I do- In this sentence comparison is not happening and i guess the rule i was talking about is valid only for the comparison based sentences.

2)She can't speak English as well as her brother: "As well as" is way different than "as" since "as well as" is more of an idiom and i assume there are numerous instances in English language where grammar gets twisted to make way for idioms

Comment: @Anmol, 1. In _Practical English Usage_ (p326) Swan discusses the uses of _like_ and _as_ in a section subtitled _similarity_. He states: _In modern English, *like* is often used as a conjunction instead of *as*. This is most common in an informal style. "You look exactly like your mother did when she was 20"_. 2. I'm not sure about _as well as_ being an idiom. But here is a different example: _She doesn't pronounce 'schedule' in the same way as her brother_. _Like_ does not fit here.

Comment: _as well as_ is unitary.

Comment: In _She can't speak English as well as her brother_,  _as well as_ could be replaced by another _as + adverb + as_ combination; for example, _as fluently as_ or _as accurately as_. As such the phrase is different from the idiomatic _as well as_ (meaning _in addition to_) in the following sentence: _She has a large vocabulary as well as a firm grasp of grammar_.